# While loop running once?

Tags: python, list, function, while-loop

New to coding and am trying to solve this coding problem to learn.

Prompt:

> If we list all the natural numbers below 10 that are multiples of 3 or 5, we get 3, 5, 6 and 9. The sum of these multiples is 23. Find the sum of all the multiples of 3 or 5 below 1000.

```
three = []
five = []

def threeList():
    n = 1
    while (n*3<1000):
        result = n*3
        three.append(result)
        n += 1
        return three

def fiveList():
    n = 1
    while (n*5<1000):
        result = n*5
        five.append(result)
        n += 1
        return five

threeList()
fiveList()

print(three,five)
```

This results in printing [3] [5] to the console.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `return` is part of the loop which means that at the end of iteration, instead of doing another iteration you just `return` from the function. Move it out of a loop, i.e.:

```
def threeList():
    n = 1
    while (n*3<1000):
        result = n*3
        three.append(result)
        n += 1
    return three
```

Also this `return` makes little sense, because you are returning global variables. No point to return something that is already available (I suggest you read about [variable scope](https://www.google.com/search?q=python%20variale%20scope)), so it's safe to get rid of these `return`s completely:

```
def threeList():
    n = 1
    while (n*3<1000):
        result = n*3
        three.append(result)
        n += 1
```

In fact, as both your functions differ very little, you should refactor your code and have just one function accepting the multiplier (as this is the only difference) and return populated list. This time we go with local variable to create the result list, so this time you need to `return` it otherwise `result` list will not be available outside the function:

```
def my_func(multiplier):
    result = []
    n = 1
    while (n*multiplier < 1000):
        result.append(n*multiplier)
        n += 1
    return result
```

and then replace

```
threeList()
fiveList()
```

with

```
three = my_func(3)
five = my_func(5)
```

In fact, you could merge this with `print()` as there's no other use for `three` and `five`, so your final code would then look like this:

```
def my_func(multiplier):
    result = []
    n = 1
    while (n*multiplier < 1000):
        result.append(n*multiplier)
        n += 1
    return result

print(my_func(3), my_func(5))
```

Comment: I knew it was something so simple! I will read about variable scope right now. Thank you!

Comment: The only nit I'd make is that while this properly captures OP's intended result, his implementation was wrong in a way you haven't corrected (duplicates probably shouldn't be added twice). Otherwise an excellent answer :)

Answer (score 3):

In addition to Marcin's fantastic answer, note that you can also do the math for which elements to use ahead of time and avoid the `while` loop entirely. [`range`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#func-range) is your friend here.

```
multiples_of_five = range(5, 1001, step=5)
multiples_of_three = range(3, 1001, 3)
```

Since `range`'s stop is *exclusive*, but we want all the multiples of three and five up to 1000 *inclusive*, we have to stop at `1001` instead. This simplifies the `my_func` that Marcin lays out above.

```
def list_multiples(n):
    result = []
    for i in range(n, 1001, n):
        result.append(i)
    return result
```

Though if we examine this more closely, you'll see we're basically just casting to list and returning. Let's do that directly.

```
def list_multiples(n):
    return list(range(n, 1001, n))
```

From there we can find the multiples of five and multiples of three

```
fives = list_multiples(5)
threes = list_multiples(3)
```

Cast to `set` to remove duplicates (15 is a multiple of both 5 and 3, but shouldn't be summed twice)

```
all_nums = set(fives + threes)
```

And sum the result

```
result = sum(all_nums)
```

Comment: While YMMV, I consider any `while` loop (except `while True`) a code smell. There are definitely places to use them, but in general you should be factoring down to a `for` loop whenever possible.

Comment: Great explanation. Will try to avoid While loops in the future. Question about "While True." Do we just use this only when we want to run a function forever?

Comment: @BenWallace any time when the "default state" is to loop, and only in exceptional cases should you break from that loop. It's common to ask for user input this way (`while True: user_in = input("some prompt"); if is_valid(user_in): break`)

Answer (score 0):

To solve your problem in Pythonic way, use [`sum()`](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/functions.html#sum) with a [generator expression](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#generator-expressions) like:

#### Code:

```
sum(i for i in range(1000) if i % 5 == 0 or i % 3 == 0)
```

#### Test Code:

```
max_num = 1000
print(sum(i for i in range(max_num) if i % 5 == 0 or i % 3 == 0))
```

#### Results:

```
233168
```

Comment: That's much easier than my attempt! Never thought to do it like this. Thanks.

Comment: While correct, this can't be considered a helpful answer for a beginner without including an explanation for how genexps work. The existing answer makes it sound like this is a feature of `sum`, rather than `sum` operating on a generator expression.

Comment: @AdamSmith You've already provided a "beginner's answer", isn't that enough? Remember that the goal of Stack Overflow is to create a useful repository of information in QnA style, and that doesn't always mean pandering to the lowest common denominator. Although some additional explanation is always helpful, the lack thereof doesn't justify the downvotes here...

Comment: @coldspeed *shrug* you may be right, but this is essentially a code-only answer which, while not _wrong_, certainly isn't great.

Comment: @AdamSmith, I have always found the notion that an answer that is a single line of code is some how inadequate.  Embrace Python.  Others have explained the basic problem with the OPs code.  But why not explain how to do it right?  20 lines of code can be replaced with one (ONE!) line of easily readable code.  Why is this a bad thing?

Comment: @StephenRauch it's not, and indeed yours is the tersest, most easily-read, _and_ most performant code here! But if the code isn't actually explained on this Q&A site, it seems a poor answer.